# Meaning of the phrase "to be used" in context

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Here it is:

> And as blatantly obvious as this is, the norm in exercise programming is to ignore it. We are taught to test a novice for his 1-rep maximum capacity on the various exercises **to be used**, none of which he really knows how to do, none of which he can do correctly, and therefore none of which he can perform well enough that a test for max effort would actually mean anything.

Is *to be used* reffered to the future there? Could it be rephrased as ...*the various exercises that will be used...*?

Answer (score 1):

There is a prospective or future sense there, because of the semantics of the sentence: *We are taught ...*

That is, the sentence is about the methods taught to evaluators (exercise instructors, presumably) looking forward to the day when they will use these methods in actual, non-pedagogic circumstances.

If you were going to rephrase that statement, rather than simply cast it in the future with **will**, you could be a little clearer by making a general statement:

> We are taught to test a novice for his one-rep maximum capacity on the various exercises *generally* used for blah-blah-blah...

Comment: I am sorry, but I am confused. Is the present simple is meant by "to be used"? For example ...vairious exercises that is used...

Comment: No, **to be used** has a prospective sense there.  It is not equivalent to **are used**.  I understand **the various exercises to be used** to mean "whatever exercises the situation calls for".  The sentence is not crystal clear.